# Cписок которой должен быть один разбился на множество списков

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Помогите почему то список которой должен быть один разбился на множество списков вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=1%24+%D0%B2+%E2%82%BD#ip=1' \

txt = 'Доллар'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text.lower(), 'lxml')
items = soup.stripped_strings
for x in items:
    if txt in x:
        #print(x)
        #print()
        text = x.split()
        print(text)
```

Вот что выходит

```
['1', 'Доллар', 'США', '=', '1', 'Доллар', 'США', '=']
['1', 'usd', '=', '91.5449', 'rub1', 'rub', '=', '0.0109', 'usd.', 'usd.', 'Российский', 'рубльrub.', 'Доллар', 'СШАusd.', 'Евроeur.', 'Австралийский', 'долларaud.', 'Азербайджанский', 'манатazn.', '1', 'usd', '=', '91.5449', 'rub1', 'rub', '=', '0.0109', 'usd.', 'usd.', 'Российский', 'рубльrub.', 'Доллар', 'СШАusd.', 'Евроeur.', 'Австралийский', 'долларaud.', 'Азербайджанский', 'манатazn.']
['ru.myfin.by', '›', 'Конвертер', 'валют', '›', 'Доллар', 'к', 'рублю', 'ru.myfin.by', '›', 'Конвертер', 'валют', '›', 'Доллар', 'к', 'рублю']
['1', 'rub', '=', '0.0109', 'usd1', 'usd', '=', '91.5449', 'rub.', 'rub.', 'Российский', 'рубльrub.', 'Доллар', 'СШАusd.', 'Евроeur.', 'Австралийский', 'долларaud.', 'Азербайджанский', 'манатazn.', '1', 'rub', '=', '0.0109', 'usd1', 'usd', '=', '91.5449', 'rub.', 'rub.', 'Российский', 'рубльrub.', 'Доллар', 'СШАusd.', 'Евроeur.', 'Австралийский', 'долларaud.', 'Азербайджанский', 'манатazn.']
['Обменный', 'курс', 'на', 'сегодня', '14.03.2024', 'составляет', '91.54', '₽', 'за', 'один', 'Доллар', 'США.', 'Введите', 'необходимую', 'сумму', 'валюты', 'для', 'конвертации,', 'и', 'вы', 'мгновенно', 'получите', 'её', '...', 'Обменный', 'курс', 'на', 'сегодня', '14.03.2024', 'составляет', '91.54', '₽', 'за', 'один', 'Доллар', 'США.', 'Введите', 'необходимую', 'сумму', 'валюты', 'для', 'конвертации,', 'и', 'вы', 'мгновенно', 'получите', 'её', '...']
```

Comment: Исправь заголовок, чтобы он отражал суть твоей проблемы. И опиши нормально в чем она заключается. [ask]

Comment: Ну и если в коде разбивать список на отдельные списки, а потом еще на отдельные слова, то не стоит потом удивляться, что код именно это и делает.

Answer (score 0):

text = x.split()
укажи разделение через строку,а не подряд.
у тебя не указан разделитель,он стоит по умолчанию(по умолчанию через 1 пробел)

Comment: А как это сделать?